# How does a microbolometer array resolve temperature?

Tags: thermal-radiation, infrared-radiation, imaging

I'm told that handheld thermal sensors measure black body radiation with a bolometer array.

I don't understand how ones goes from IR photon counts to temperature. Is the camera somehow spectrally resolved?

[image]

Comment: It says in the very first sentence of the Wikipedia article on Microbolometers that these devices work by the sensor material changing its electrical resistance in response to temperature changes.

Comment: @SamuelWeir there's a potential for confusion here because there are two relevant temperatures: the temp of the bolometer element (which results in a measurable, calibrated resistance change) and the temp of the imaged object (which results in blackbody radiation incident on the bolometer array, thereby increasing the bolometer pixel temperature).  If left long enough to achieve equilibrium, bolometer pixel would simply rise in temperature to match that of the object.  But I don't know how long that takes.

Comment: A point of clarification: bolometers don't count photons.  Rather, they measure a temperature change (in a piece of material) due to absorbed light.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Yeah to clarify, i'm not interest in how the bolometer expands. I'm interest in how that expansion related to the temperature of the object. It is my understanding that the array is not distinct from a deep IR camera in the sense that it measures the number of caught photons over some wavelength range.

Comment: Again, bolometers do not count photons. They are, essentially, black bodies being warmed by whatever is putting out thermal radiation. How much they are warmed is a measure of how hot the body emitting radiation is.

Comment: @JonCuster I know that the material changes resistance after temperature raise due to IR absorption, and that change is calibrated and mapped to the temperature. However, I do have a question regarding how the detector cools down to a baseline temperature for new measureemnts. Should the heat accumulates and thus there will be a cooling down time for the detector during which it is not usable?